# GlassFish Security Realm, Active Directory and Referral

Tags: java, active-directory, glassfish

I've setup up a Security Realm in Glassfish to authenticate against an Active Directory server. The configuration of the realm is as follows:

```
Class Name: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm
JAAS context:  ldapRealm
Directory: ldap://172.16.76.10:389/
Base DN:  dc=smallbusiness,dc=local
search-filter: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))
group-search-filter: (&(objectClass=group)(member=%d))
search-bind-dn: cN=Administrator,CN=Users,dc=smallbusiness,dc=local
search-bind-password: abcd1234!
```

The realm is functional and I can log-in, but when ever I log in I get the following error in the log:

```
SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=Administrator,CN=Users,dc=smallbusiness,dc=local))].
SEC1000: Caught exception.
    javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'dc=smallbusiness,dc=local'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
        ....
        ....
ldaplm.searcherror
```

While searching for a solution I found that it was recommended to add `java.naming.referral=follow` to the properties of the realm. However, after I add this it takes 20 minutes for GlassFish to authenticate against Active Directory. I suspect it is a DNS problem on the Active Directory server. The Active Directory server is a vanilla Windows Server 2003 setup in a Virtual Machine.

Any help/recommendation is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was maddening trying to solve this... Glassfish 3.0.1 trying to connect with Windows, and getting the above error.

I'm not a Windows or LDAP whiz at all... but finally found this:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=87673

And the very last line is the key: use the "Global Catalog Port" - instead of 389, it is 3268 by default. And the exception disappears.

Why?

Who cares?

(well, ok, I'm going to read about it now.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the configuration I use in my domain.xml file, it might be of some interrest to you :

```
<auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm" name="ldapRealm"> 
      <property name="search-bind-password" value="Demodemo01"/> 
      <property name="search-bind-dn" value="Administrator"/> 
      <property name="search-filter" value="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))"/> 
      <property name="group-search-filter" value="(&amp;(objectClass=group)(member=%d))"/> 
      <property name="jaas-context" value="ldapRealm"/> 
      <property name="base-dn" value="CN=Users,DC=saierp,DC=net"/> 
      <property name="directory" value="ldap://192.168.1.38:389"/> 
</auth-realm>
```

Specially, make sure to add the `userAccountControl` to your filter, otherwise, disabled accounts in AD will be allowed to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you've resolved this, but just in case:

1. I used 'objectCategory' in place of 'objectClass' as I read the former are indexed, hence faster.
2. I had to add this property:

   property name="assign-groups" value="Domain Users"

where "Domain Users" is the group in AD that all of our users are placed into.  This must match the value in sun-web.xml for security-role-mapping.

Later, I was able to create a specific group for this application and make the appropriate changes.